# Synchronized scrolling in two windows

Tags: window, scrolling, navigation, minor-mode

Is there a way to reflect the navigation commands in the current window in another visible window. I have two related LaTeX files displayed in two windows and would like to scroll through them simultaneously to get an overview of the differences. I currently use a macro to automate scrolling in one buffer, moving to the other window, and scrolling and then moving back.

Ediff has an inbuilt way of doing this in `ediff-scroll-vertically` bound to `v` , so I was wondering if emacs already has one built in. Ideally I would like a minor mode that mirrors navigation in all visible windows.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`M-x scroll-all-mode` does exactly that.

You can also refer to the [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollAllMode) on `scroll-all-mode` and how to make synchronized scrolling work with mouse scrolling.

Comment: This doesn't quite work with Evil mode especially if you jump around from line to line, the scrolling becomes un-synchronized.

Comment: It'd be awesome to have something a bit more robust.