# Linked, Split screen scrolling for a single buffer?

Tags: window-splitting, scrolling

I would like to be able to have

- a `C-x 3` split to have two windows in a frame
- both windows view a single buffer
- window on left ends at line n
- window on right starts at line n +/- configurable offset
- vertical scrolling action scrolls BOTH windows

Does something like this already exist?

Comment: I think what you are asking for is different enough from this that it's not a duplicate, but you should look at this, it might be good enough for you purposes, it doesn't do the n-line configuration you're taking about, but you can use it to open a file in two windows, use jump down a page in one buffer, enable this mode and then you have what you want I think. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/288/synchronized-scrolling-in-two-windows

Comment: Thanks Jordon - I found follow-mode (which handles displaying a single buffer in multiple windows) from following your suggestion.  Your link suggest scroll-all-mode which allows linked scrolling of different buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest existing tool to what I have asked for is `follow-mode`:

- Emacs wiki: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FollowMode
- Source in Emacs mirror on Github: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/follow.el

Cliffs:

- `M-x follow-mode` to trigger manually
- `(setq follow-auto t)` to trigger automatically
- `C-c . 1` or `M-x follow-delete-other-windows-and-split` to maximise the current buffer in a two column format