# Freeze column for org table

Tags: org-table

Is there something like [org-table-sticky-header](https://github.com/cute-jumper/org-table-sticky-header/), but for columns?

Context:
I am trying to create a table like this and add columns to it every day:

[image]

I already figured out that I need `toggle-truncate-lines`, so that my table doesn't get wrapped once it gets longer, but ideally I'd be able to add more and more coloumns while still being able to see the first column with the Questions.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/288/synchronized-scrolling-in-two-windows)?